# docker desktop use container network alias as environment var for another container

Tags: docker, variables, networking, containers, environment

Getting up to speed with Docker, and I'm stuck trying to pass the network identity (ip + port) of one container as an environment variable to another. I'm using Docker Desktop and running each container in its own terminal session, using a docker network already created.

For example:
ServerContainer:

- has a network alias of 'backend'
- exposes port 5000
- is visible in a browser as 'http://localhost:5000'

AppContainer:

- has a network alias of 'frontend'
- needs the network identity of ServerContainer as an environment variable

For the AppContainer ('frontend') when I run

```
docker run -dp 3000:3000 --network <network name> --network-alias frontend -e THE_SERVER_CONTAINER_IDENTITY=http://localhost:5000 <image for frontend>
```

everything works.

However, this doesn't seem like a good idea. Better would be to use the ServerContainer ('backend') network identity as the environment var, such as:

```
docker run -dp 3000:3000 --network <network name> --network-alias frontend -e THE_SERVER_CONTAINER_IDENTITY=backend <image for frontend>
```

However, 'backend' shows up as the env variable value. What is needed is the network identity from ServerContainer ('backend'), not the word 'backend'.

So. Two questions then:

1. Is it possible to extract / dereference / 'decode' the network identity of the 'backend' container?
2. If possible, how to do this when starting the 'frontend' container?

If my approach is off-base and there is a better way to solve this, please let me know. This looks like a really simple solution, but I just can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you for your time and attention.

Comment: Where and how does that environment variable get used?  If the "frontend" container actually serves a browser application (say, a React or Angular app) then that runs in the end user's browser, not a container, and it can't use Docker networking features; it knows nothing about the Docker network name or Docker-internal DNS names.

Comment: Yes, 'frontend' is a React app. It needs 'backend' to get data, of course, so it needs to know where to ask for that data.

I sort of understand what you're saying in the above comment, as well as what you've written in other replies to similar problems. But I just can't get my head around how something so seemly simple is so complicated. Pages and pages of documentation aren't clarifying this.

To read 'Docker containers can talk to each other by service name', and then encountering a simple situation where they don't seem to be able to do that, with no way forward, is really confusing.

Comment: To reiterate: the React application runs in the browser, which is not a Docker container.

Answer (score -1):

changing 'localhost' in:

```
THE_SERVER_CONTAINER_IDENTITY=http://localhost:5000
```

to '0.0.0.0' ie:

```
THE_SERVER_CONTAINER_IDENTITY=http://0.0.0.0:5000
```

seems to work.

Not sure if this is the best solution. I'd prefer to directly reference the 'backend' ip, but for now it's a fix.

Leaving this post up in hopes it will help other.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is a special IP address that means "listen on all interfaces".  It doesn't really make sense to include it in a URL.  If you do, I believe it generally means the exact same thing as `localhost`.

Comment: I tried it again, using 'localhost', and now it works. No idea why it was failing before. Being really tired probably has something to do with it...

Thanks for nudging me in this direction.